# Chrome addon to view PHP and Apache errors on my server

Tags: chrome, php, debugging, programming, apache

Optional informative rant:

> When testing PHP code, I often use Chrome browser. To read PHP and
>   Apache error/debug messages, I use LTF Viewer.
>
> This is getting annoying because I'd have to switch to-and-fro between
>   the three programs: the PHP code editor, the browser to test the page,
>   and the error viewer. Having the error viewer built into the browser
>   would save alot of pain.

Is there a Chrome addon to view a server's PHP and Apache errors?

It **must be able to handle large log files**, on the order of millions of lines. (This shouldn't be a problem because I'd only be [tailing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1475419/632951) anyway.)

Plain text view would be sufficient, though preferably a toggle option to enable more "advanced" views like color-coding depending on the error type.

Comment: Have you tried XDebugger? As far as I can tell, the browser alone can't view your php source code or erros. But however, one step to go is if you use IDE such as Netbeans, you can use php debugger and install the debugger Plugin in Chrome so Netbeans and Chrome could be able to talk to each other, if your php script breaks then Netbeans will automatically open and show you the line where you set it to break. Moreover, Netbeans has a built in browser where you can view your site in a separate panel. So if your screen is bit enough, and your PC is quite powerful then using Netbeans should be ok

Comment: @Joraid, The error logs are located in the filesystem and Chrome plugins can read the filesystem. No the built-in browser is practically useless. Testing must be done on real browsers that users use. Btw, by XDebugger, do you mean [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Browsers are totally ignorant of the existence of PHP (or ASP, or Ruby, or Python, or anything server-side), they just parse the HTML/CSS/Javascript they output. The same with webservers, they just see "something that replies HTTP requests". But if your test server is in the same computer, you can try browsing using the file:// "protocol" and opening the text log files with the browser from the local filesystem, then reloading when needed.

Comment: @Alejandro, This is definitely possible because my dev machine is on the VPN. Yes they are not on the same computer, but they're on the same network, thus file accessible using the [double backslash](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/171054-what-is-the-difference-between-one-backslash-and-double-backslashes-when-defining-a-path).